# Eager loading in controller in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app, posts has many tags.

the tags are connected through a join table, join_tags

In my index view, which lists all the posts, I do something like so:

```
<% post.tags.each do |tag| %>
    <%= tag.name %>,                                
<% end %>
```

The problem here, is its hitting the database for each post to load the tags.

Is there a way to load all of the tags for these tasks once in the controller? Maybe through the @Posts var? I have a feeling its through eager loading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, and as you said, [eager loading](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) is the right way to achieve this, you may want to do something like this in your controller action:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.includes(:tags).all
end
```

Assuming you have the following relationships in your post model:

```
has_many :join_tags
has_many :tags, :through => :join_tags
```

It will save you the n+1 post-tag queries.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see your controller code, but I think you're looking for something like:

```
@posts = Post.all(:include => :tags)
```

Comment: actually +1 to jpemberthy's answer, beat me to the punch with a more up to date answer.